# How much health does a maniac have in COD: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

The kill-streak called "Maniac" doesn't let you regenerate health.

How much damage can you actually take before dying when you're using the maniac killstreak?

Comment: they have the same healthpool as a a regular Juggernaut, although I'm not sure how much that is. You might know.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the Maniac you can take 4 Throwng knifes before dying, or 5 Knife swings. you can also take 4 Bites from a Attack Dog. And they can also take 34 AK-12 Rounds before Dying.

Comment: And they can also take 34 AK-12 Rounds before Dying